# How to confirm the ScheduledExecutorService is setup correctly (and still running in the future)

Tags: java, scheduling

I have a Java method that uses the ScheduledExecutorService to schedule a task to run periodically.

I'd like to include code to check that:

1. The task was scheduled successfully (i.e. to return true)
2. The `run()` part is attempted (now, and in the future), and invoke method: doOtherStuff() if ever the run part doesn't work

I was thinking of using try/catch to achieve this.  Am I thinking along the right lines?

My code is something like this:

```
private void scheduleCheck()
{
    ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();

    executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() 
    {
        // Task to be scheduled
        public void run() 
        {               
            periodicCheck();
        }
    }, 1, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}
```

For 1. Should I just be adding a try/catch around the code scheduling the task, with a boolean variable set to true if the 'try' part runs to the end.

For 2. Can I again just use a try/catch within the run()  section, with a method invoked in the catch bit (should the run fail).

I was thinking something along these lines.  Can anyone see anything I'm missing, or any obvious flaws in my logic?

```
    private boolean scheduleCheck()
{
    boolean isScheduled = false;
    try
    {
        ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
        executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() 
        {
            // Task to be scheduled
            public void run() 
            {               
                try
                {
                    periodicCheck();
                }
                catch(java.lang.exception e)
                {
                    doOtherStuff();
                }
            }
        }, 1, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        isScheduled = true;
    }
    catch(java.lang.exception e)
    {
    }
    return isScheduled;
}
```